# How to find a new hard drive for my old-ish HP computer

Tags: hard-drive, compatibility

I own an [HP a1211n](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c00503713&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=1118267&prodTypeId=12454) whose harddrive recently passed away, RIP.

I want to buy it a new hard drive but I'm not sure which will be compatible.
I know it needs to be a SATA, but I don't know what further I need to look for.

Comment: Downvoter, care to come out and explain?

Comment: Perhaps someone doesn't like queries that are "simple" by their standards. :/ I cancelled out the downvote for you.

Comment: @Karan Thank you. I know it wasn't the most sophisticated question, but I couldnt find a clear answer anywhere, and I made sure to use words that will help people in the same situation find this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much any desktop 3.5" SATA drive should be fine. SATA 3 Gbps and SATA 6 Gbps are both backwards compatible, so even newer drives should work without any problems.

**Note:** If you're going to reinstall XP on an [Advanced Format drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format), you'll need to align partitions since XP isn't AF–aware. See your drive's documentation for details (generally they'll provide a recommended utility for this).

Comment: FYI 2.5" SATA is compatible also, just need mounting brackets.

Comment: @Keltari: True, but didn't want to complicate things further. A simple desktop drive should suffice as a drop–in replacement.

Comment: yes, but if he has a spare 2.5" drive, then he doesnt need to buy a new disk.

Comment: @Keltari Thanks, but I don't have an old 2.5 anyway. Good to know though

Comment: @Karan If you're still there, can you tell with certainty [if this hard drive](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=1102922&CatId=2458) will work with my HP a1211n?